# Windows Installation cancelled because a required driver could not be installed

Tags: windows

I'm installing windows directly to an iSCSI target and I'm getting this error:

Windows Installation cancelled because a required driver could not be installed

How do I get around this?  Is there a log file where I can discover just what the required driver it is that is unable to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.  It could be related to this issue!

[Cross-platform iSCSI boot deployment scenarios are not supported.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967754/en-us)

I found the setup error log files were located in:

e:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log

I'm testing this now with some x64 only based media as I was using a i386/x64 media from MSDN previously.

Comment: Yuck! strange but true.  Using 64bit windows media fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You get around this by installing the required driver during setup.  (Assuming you're doing a clean, custom install.  If you're not, you may run into this issue because... well, bug.)

Precisely how you do this depends on the version of Windows you're trying to install, which you haven't specified.  And no, there's no log, but your OEM should be aware of the issue and have a KB telling you to install the appropriate drivers, and how.

As to which driver it is, it's usually a disk or RAID driver.  So that's where I'd start.  Get the relevant iSCSI drivers, and if appropriate, any drivers for your RAID card prepped so you can provide them to Windows during the setup.